# Google Sheet: Query to select both Col1 and Col2

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I'm using Google Sheet to scrape the web data and would like to select both col1 and col2 together. I tried to use the XPath "and" operator to add the selection but it prompts out "Unable to parse query string". How should I edit the code below to make it work?

=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select Col1 and Col2 limit 10",-1)

Comment: Can I ask you about the values you expect?

Comment: I want to select all the col data, using the link above, in the second row I want to select both the sentences "OTHERS" (from col1) and "Press release ..." (from col2)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your replying, for example, this modified formula `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select Col1, Col2 limit 10",-1)` is what you want?

Comment: By the way, can I ask you about the detail of `select` of `I want to select all the col data` you are thinking? For example, you want to activate the columns?

Comment: =MATCH("*ACQUISITION*", QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"select Col1, Col2 limit 10",-1))
 
Actually the purpose I query the data is to check whether the appearance of the specific words and hence I will be able to get notified of a specific event when it occurs. Your code is working ^^, when I add the match condition it prompts "MATCH range must be a single row or a single column", any way to deal with this error?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about this formula? `=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"ACQUISITION")` In this case, when `ACQUISITION` included in the retrieved data, `TRUE` is returned. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the solution that I'm looking for, thanks a lot! When I first publish this question I never think about the match condition will contradict the query function. Would you like to post your solution as a reply so that I can uptick it as the answer and upvote it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From our discussions, I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to retrieve 10 rows from `div[@class='card-body']`, I think that you can achieve it using a xpath as follows.

#### Sample formula 1:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[@class='announcements']/a[position()<=10]//div[@class='card-body']")
```

##### Result:

[image]

#### Sample formula 2:

When you want to check whether the value of `ACQUISITION` is included in the retrieved values, how about the following sample formula?

##### Sample 1:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")),"ACQUISITION")
```

- This is from the comment.

##### Sample 2:

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[@class='announcements']/a[position()<=10]//div[@class='card-body']")),"ACQUISITION")
```

- In this case, `ACQUISITION` is retrieved from 10 rows. And, when the value of `ACQUISITION` is included, `TRUE` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342/importxml)

Comment: Yes, these are the solutions demanded. Thanks a lot!
Just now I tested that the regexmatch will check the uppercase and lowercase of the matched word hence I put it as "ACQUISITION | Acquisition | acquisition".

Comment: @Philip Chow Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look if the formula is showing the result you want?:

```
=query(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/announcements/stock/5199", "//div[@class='card-body']"),"limit 10")
```

[image]

Comment: It gives me another sight of just using "limit 10" will be enough haha. Thanks for the answer.